# php function to change 100,200,300 into array of 100=100,200=200,300=300

Tags: php, arrays, string, get

I'm no php programmer at all. But I ask for help with a function.

Imagine URL parameter like ?MyParam=100,200,300

Desired php function should get value from MyParam parameter and return array, which suppose to look like:

```
$choices = array(
'100' => '100',
'200' => '200',
'300' => '300'
);
return $choices;
```

Many thanks

Comment: Well we can't help you, this website is meant for helping programmers with their code, you need to give us a code to start.

Comment: `explode` your parameter by `,` then use `array_combine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode your param :

```
<?php 
$choices = explode(',', $_GET['myParam']);
return $choices;
```

`$choices` will be an array containing `[100,200,300]`.

If you want to have the keys the same as the values, you can do :

```
<?php
$array = array_combine($choices, $choices);
return $array;
```